# CSS in site.css not working with <div id> in layout in asp.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get this:

[image]

But i am getting this:

[image]

My _Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title> 
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js")" 
type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>
<body>
 <div id="header"> 
        <div class="title">SPORTS STORE</div> 
     </div> 
     <div id="categories"> 
         @{Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav");} 
     </div> 
     <div id="content"> 
        @RenderBody() 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Menu.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<string> 

@{ 
    Layout = null; 
} 

@Html.ActionLink("Home", "List", "Product") 

@foreach (var link in Model)
{ 
    @Html.RouteLink(link, new
                          {
                              controller = "Product",
                              action = "List",
                              category = link,
                              page = 1
                          }) 
}
```

My site.css:

```
BODY { font-family: Cambria, Georgia, "Times New Roman"; margin: 0; }
DIV#header DIV.title, DIV.item H3, DIV.item H4, DIV.pager A {
    font: bold 1em "Arial Narrow", "Franklin Gothic Medium", Arial;
}
DIV#header { background-color: #444; border-bottom: 2px solid #111; color: White; }
DIV#header DIV.title { font-size: 2em; padding: .6em; }
DIV#content { border-left: 2px solid gray; margin-left: 9em; padding: 1em; }
DIV#categories { float: left; width: 8em; padding: .3em; }

DIV.item { border-top: 1px dotted gray; padding-top: .7em; margin-bottom: .7em; }
DIV.item:first-child { border-top:none; padding-top: 0; }
DIV.item H3 { font-size: 1.3em; margin: 0 0 .25em 0; }
DIV.item H4 { font-size: 1.1em; margin:.4em 0 0 0; }

DIV.pager { text-align:right; border-top: 2px solid silver;
    padding: .5em 0 0 0; margin-top: 1em; }
DIV.pager A { font-size: 1.1em; color: #666; text-decoration: none;
      padding: 0 .4em 0 .4em; }
DIV.pager A:hover { background-color: Silver; }
DIV.pager A.selected { background-color: #353535; color: White; }

DIV#categories A  
{
    font: bold 1.1em "Arial Narrow","Franklin Gothic Medium",Arial; display: block;
    text-decoration: none; padding: .6em; color: Black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}
DIV#categories A.selected { background-color: #666; color: White; }
DIV#categories A:hover { background-color: #CCC; }
DIV#categories A.selected:hover { background-color: #666; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example is from ASP.NET MVC 3 PRO book. I have tried this and this has worked for me. I suggest you refer to the code download or check your code is properly.

From what you have in the code it seems like correct but you probably need to refresh your cache or check what is getting rendered using developer tools such as Firebug.

Here is what it should be in **Firebug** for div id=categories

```
DIV#categories {
    float: left;
    padding: 0.3em;
    width: 8em;
}
```

and for a tags inside that.

```
DIV#categories A {
    border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
    color: Black;
    display: block;
    font: bold 1.1em "Arial Narrow","Franklin Gothic Medium",Arial;
    padding: 0.6em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: I am using MVC 4, but yes, it is from the MVC 3 pro book. 

I have tried to copy paste the code with no luck. Is it because I am running MVC 4?

Comment: @CasperHansen I don't think if there will be any difference between MVC3 and MVC4. Check the Firebug and see if the rendered output are as I mentioned before.